# How to change custom layout inside RecyclerView using single custom dialog class?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have many CardViews and i want to show the custom Dialog on every cardView click i created a class MyDialog that extends DialogFragmnent i want to pass the layout file inside the RecyclerView using one of my class "MyDialog" method getData(int resource) but when i am calling it it showing an error and app got crashed.

This is my Dialog Class:

```
 public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
     int resource;
     public void getData(int resource)
       {
         this.resource=resource;
       }

     @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(resource,null));

        return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

This is My onBindViewHolder method

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder( MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  Model model=albums.get(position);
  holder.category_name.setText(model.getCategory());
  holder.items_count.setText(model.getItems());
  holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(model.getThumbnail());
    Glide.with(context).load(model.getThumbnail());
 holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         String n=albums.get(position).getCategory();
          myDialog=new MyDialog();

         if (n.equals("Burger"))
         {
             myDialog.getData(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
             fm=((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
             myDialog.show(fm,"my_dialog");
         }
         if (n.equals("Burger"))
         {
             myDialog.getData(R.layout.chawomin);
             fm=((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
             myDialog.show(fm,"my_dialog");
         }


     }
 });

}
```

Comment: It must be crashing because your `if` condition is the same, `if (n.equals("Burger"))` ,

Comment: I resolved this issue thank you for reply.